# How to put my academic roll no in latex beamer title slide

Tags: beamer

I am making a slides on latex beamer for my academic exam..I need to put my class roll number on the title side but how to do so...

I am using command

```
`\usetheme{Darmstadt}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\hspace*{.2cm}\scriptsize{\insertauthor
\hspace*{30pt} \hfill\insertframenumber\hspace*{.5cm}}} 

\title {my topics title}

\author{my name}
%% I need my roll no to show here

\institute[CU]{
 my institute\\[\medskipamount]
      \includegraphics[width=.23\textwidth,height=.31\textheight]{cu1.jpg}%
 }

\date{23 rd February, 2013}`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add it on the `\author` command; for example:

```
\author{My name (roll #)}
```

or in a second line

```
\author{My name \\ {\small roll #}}
```

Comment: Hi zunbeltz. A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or select your code and hit Ctrl+K.